# Why are club colors not always visible when playing online?

Tags: rocket-league

I created a Rocket League club with a friend on Xbox One and we set our club colors to white and teal.  When we play online, sometimes our team color is white, while other times our team color is the standard blue/orange configuration.

What factors dictate whether or not club colors are visible in an online match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On each team, everyone on that team needs to be in the same club.  If even one player on either team isn't in the same club as his teammates, the game won't be a club-match.